# recursively make directory tree in puppet without purging

Tags: puppet

I want to create the directory structure `/var/www/apps/example/current/public` if it doesn't exist using puppet. If it already exists I don't want to purge the contents of the directories. How do I do this? Below is what I have so far:

```
file { "/var/www/apps/example/current/public":
  owner => 'deploy',
  group => 'users',
  ensure => "directory",
  purge => false,
  recurse => true
}
```

This gives me

```
 Cannot create /var/www/apps/example/current/public; parent directory /var/www/apps/example/current does not exist
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `recurse` parameter does not allow you to create parent directories. It is used to enforce property values such as `owner`, `mode` etc. on directory contents and subdirectories recursively.

```
file { '/var/www':
    owner   => 'www-data',
    recurse => true,
}
```

As a matter of fact, Puppet currently cannot automatically create all parent directories. You should add all relevant directories as resources instead.

```
file { [ '/var/www/apps',
         '/var/www/apps/example',
         '/var/www/apps/example/current',
         '/var/www/apps/example/current/public', ]:
           ensure => directory,
           ...
}
```

Existing content will remain unmolested. There is no need to pass the `purge` parameter.

Answer (score 12):

```
  exec { "Create ${mydir}":
    creates => $mydir,
    command => "mkdir -p ${mydir}",
    path => $::path
  } -> file { $mydir : }
```

The last line is so that other resources (e.g., files to create inside `$mydir`) can depend on `File[$mydir]` as though it was possible to create it with a plain old `file {}` block, [which it really should](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/86).

Answer (score 2):

If you use "define", you can have something like this:

```
mymodule::recursive_dir { "My Directory" :
   drive => "C:",
   path  => "/path/to/folder",
}
```

Where I define the "define" in mymodule.rb:

```
define mymodule::recursive_dir ($drive, $path) {
  $folders = split($path, "/")
  $folders.each |$index, $folder| {
    $calculated_folder = inline_template("<%= @folders[0, @index + 1].join('/') %>")
    $full_path = "${drive}${calculated_folder}"
    if (! defined(File[$full_path]) and $full_path != $drive) {
      file { $full_path :
        ensure => directory,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This splits apart the path and creates each directory as it puts the path back together, making sure not to try to create the drive itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that puppet will not make parent directories for you, but you can easily create a file-like provider that does do this. As an example, I created a custom type and provider to basically run 'mkdir -p' on POSIX systems: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_namespaces.html

There's a really good reason, however, that Puppet does not do this by default. That's because Puppet doesn't want to be responsible for your permissions across several directories, since the agent runs as root. That could be bad if you're provisioning /var/www or something.

The recuse file parameter is really meant to manage directory tree parameters: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-recurse

You can create your directory tree and serve it using the source => 'puppet:///' uri for example, set recurse to true, and it'll use all the file modes that are set on the directory tree being served.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a good solution but failed. So I figured out a way myself. Hopefully it's useful to other people.

The following function will generate the list of parent directories, then we can use the list to build parent folders. The first argument is the path that is used as the starting point to search parent directories; the second argument is optional and it's used as the ending point (exclusive) to stop looking up:

```
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
  newfunction(:parentdirs, :type => :rvalue, :doc => <<-EOS
    Build a list of all its parent directories.
    EOS
  ) do |arguments|

    raise(Puppet::ParseError, "parentdirs(): Wrong number of arguments " +
      "given (#{arguments.size} for 1)") if arguments.size < 1

    $dir_until = arguments.size > 1 ? arguments[1] : nil
    $cur = File.dirname(arguments[0])
    $result = []
    begin
        $result.unshift($cur)
        $last = $cur
        $cur = File.dirname($cur)
    end while $cur != $last and !$cur.end_with?('/') and $cur != $dir_until

    return $result
  end
end
```

Here is an example how to use it:

```
$my_folder = '/var/www/apps/example/current/public'
$parent_dirs = parentdirs($my_folder, '/var/www/apps')
file { $parent_dirs:
  ensure => 'directory',
  owner => 'deploy',
  group => 'users'
}
file { $my_folder:
  ensure => 'directory',
  owner => 'deploy',
  group => 'anonymous'
}
```

The above codes will ensure folders '/var/www/apps/example' and '/var/www/apps/example/current' created before creating '/var/www/apps/example/current/public' while '/var/www/apps/example' and above remain not being touched.

I only tested it in Windows. But it should work in Linux environment.

This is not ideal. But it's better than listing all parents one by one manually.

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you to **AnthonyY**.

I didn't know where to put the code for his function, and as a result of my research ended up rewriting the whole thing using the newer syntax, but keeping his logic.

It took me *quite a while* to work it all out, so I figured it would be good to post it back here. ...I would have just added it as a comment to his answer, but apparently I need 50 points to do that, not zero.

The code should be saved in it's own file inside your Puppet environment directory as follows:

```
lib/puppet/functions/parentdirs.rb
```

...so the full path would be something like this (on Ubuntu server 18.04, using the Puppet packages, not the repo ones):

```
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/testing/lib/puppet/functions/parentdirs.rb
```

...there seem to be other places you can put it, but this is what I did.

Notice that the file is `.rb`, not `.pp` (because it's Ruby code, not Puppet).

I got most of my information from https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/functions_ruby_overview.html and the sub-pages.

The usage is the same as the original function, and somewhat re-explained in the comments

```
# Returns an array of the parent directories to the given file or directory. This can then be passed to File to create the directory tree require for a dynamic path value.
# Parameter 2 is an optional, higher level of the same path. These higher level directories will not be in the array.
# Example 1: parameter 1 is '/var/www/mysite'; parameter 2 is not given; returns array ['/var', '/var/www']
# Example 2: parameter 1 is '/var/www/mysite'; parameter 2 is '/var'; returns array ['/var/www']

Puppet::Functions.create_function(:parentdirs) do

  dispatch :parents do
    required_param 'String', :target_dir
    optional_param 'String', :dir_until
    return_type 'Array'
  end


  def parents(target_dir, dir_until = '')

    cur = File.dirname(target_dir)
    result = []

    begin
        result.unshift(cur)
        last = cur
        cur = File.dirname(cur)
    end while cur != last and !cur.end_with?('/') and cur != dir_until

    return result

  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a pure puppet solution to do `mkdir -p $(dirname $file_path)`

```
$file_path = '/tmp/foo/bar/bob.conf' # assumes file_path is Stdlib::Unixpath
# strip leading '/' then split and loop
$dirs = $file_path[1,-1].dirname.split('/').reduce([]) |$memo, $subdir| {
    $_dir =  $memo.empty ? { 
        true    => "/${subdir}",
        default => "${$memo[-1]}/${subdir}",
    }     
    concat($memo, $_dir)
}
file {$dirs:
    ensure => directory,
}
```